# Read the current pageurl from the url using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, variables

So i have this url, like this:

`index.html#page:page.php`

Because i load my pages using AJAX i want to set somekinda hotlink to load that page...

'Cause im using this function now:

```
function getdata(file){

    $('#content').fadeOut('slow', function () { 
        $.get(file, function(data) {
            $('#content').html(data);
            $('#content').fadeIn('slow');
        })
    })

}
```

And i want to make something like this

```
// if #page is set and #page isn't empty
getdata('src/'+ that-page);
```

and in the menu: 
`<a href="#page:contact.php" onclick="getdata('src/contact.php');">Contact</a>`

So that the URL than is index.php#page:contact.php and if someone goes to that url that he does this:

```
// if #page is set and #page isn't empty
    getdata('src/'+ that-page);
```

I hope it is clear now...

So how can i read what is behind `#page:` in the URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the page's hash as it's stored in `window.location.hash`.

To parse it and only get the filename that you're looking for, you'll want to do something like this:

```
// #page:test.php
var page = window.location.hash;
    page = page.replace('#page:', '');

alert(page); // test.php
```

Also, don't call the variable `that-page` as it'll fail.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
```

Answer (score 1):

And you can reduce calls to selector "#content", saving it in a variable:

```
$content = $('#content');
$content.fadeOut('slow', function () {
    $.get(file, function(data) {
        $content.html(data);
        $content.fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

=)